# how to fetch JSONObject with array of objects

Tags: java, json

I have json string data like:

```
 {"contactlist":["{"id":"1","mobile":"186010855","name":"Intex"}","{"id":"212","mobile":"980067","name":"pari"}"]}
```

I want to fetch all data means id,mobile and name for all..
So, I have Contact Class :

```
public class Contact {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String mobile;
    //getters and settrs & constructors
    }
```

and for fetching I have tried:

```
       String stringdata=
              "{"contactlist":["{"id":"1","mobile":"186010855","name":"Intex"}","
                {"id":"212","mobile":"980067","name":"pari"}"]}";
         try{ 
            Contact contact1 = new Contact();
            contact1 = new Gson().fromJson(contactreceive, Contact.class);
            Contact contact = new Contact(contact1.getId(),contact1.getName(),
                                            contact1.getMobile());

                System.out.println (contact);
          }catch(Exception e){

           }
```

But I can not fetch data like this..how can I fetch this json data?

Comment: I think you are deserializing and not fetching it. And JSON also is an invalid JSON. Please post a valid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, as per @ShubhamChaurasia 's comment. The following JSON validates:

```
{
    "contactlist": [{
        "id": "1",
        "mobile": "186010855",
        "name": "Intex"
    },
    {
        "id": "212",
        "mobile": "980067",
        "name": "pari"
    }]
}
```

Escape this in Java as you have already been shown (with `\"`) and this will stop your JSON validation errors. I recommend combining this with @Joopkins ' or @JanTheGun 's answer.

A good site I use for JSON validation is http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes to get a valid json string. Then you can read the json array like this:

```
String stringdata = "{\"contactlist\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"mobile\":\"186010855\",\"name\":\"Intex\"},{\"id\":\"212\",\"mobile\":\"980067\",\"name\":\"pari\"}]}";

JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(stringdata);
JsonObject jsonOject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonOject.getAsJsonArray("contactlist");

for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
    JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();

    String id = obj.get("id").toString();
    String name = obj.get("name").toString();
    String mobile = obj.get("mobile").toString();

    Contact contact = new Contact(id, name, mobile);
    System.out.println("id: " + contact.getId());
    System.out.println("name: " + contact.getName());
    System.out.println("mobile: " + contact.getMobile());
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Error: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 21

Comment: Did you escape the double quotes in your json string?

Comment: Yes, I have used replace("\\", "");

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the stringdata into a JSONArray containing a JSONObject for each contact.

```
    JSONObject contactData = new JSONObject(stringdata);
    JSONArray contactArray = contactData.getJSONArray("contactlist");
    //Create an array of contacts to store the data
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[contactArray.length()];
    //Step through the array of JSONObjects and convert them to your Java class
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for(int i = 0; i < contactArray.length(); i++){
         contacts[i] = gson.fromJson(
              contactArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Contact.class);
          }
```

Now you have an array of Contacts from your raw JSON data.

Comment: Error: Expected a ',' or ']' at 20 [character 21 line 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject contactData = new JSONObject(stringdata);
JSONArray contactArray = contactData.getJSONArray("contactlist");
for(int i=0;i<contactArray .length;i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject=contactArray.getJSONObject(i));
    String id=jsonObject.getString("id")

    String key=jsonObject.getString("key")
}
```